# How can I adjust the video height to fit the parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on fitting the background video to fit the parent div but it is not adjusting to the height within the media query. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="/videos/aerial(2).mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .hero{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}


#myVideo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1; 
     filter: brightness(65%);
     height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #myVideo {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #myVideo {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The CSS you provided is working - the video is at the bottom, behind the other content, with 100% width and automatic height.

Comment: @MfyDev I want the video to expand in height for the whole parent div meaning that I want the video to cover the whole with of the .hero element

Comment: Set the video height to `100%` and add `object-fit: cover;`. That will make the video fill the whole area.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to achieve with those media queries. For many (most?) viewport aspect ratios the video won't fit exactly and as I guess  you don't want it to stretched you need to use object-fit as suggested by @davidleininger - either to cover, when some of the video will be cut but the whole viewport will be filled, or to contain when the whole video will be shown but wont cover the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the video to cover its parent in height and keep the ratio, you could use `height:100%` - stretch to 100% of the parent in height - and `width:auto` - width will be adjusted relative to height to keep the original ratio.

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  #myVideo {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #myVideo {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

If your video overflows the parent container when this CSS is applied, add `box-sizing:border-box` to the style of `#myVideo` so that `height:100%` is calculated with padding.

For mobile (portrait) screens, the values are flipped to fit the screen.

To resolve the orientation, use the `orientation` media query.

**EDIT:** If the `orientation` doesn't work, use the `min`/`max-aspect-ratio`. Min. `1/1` is landscape and max. `1/1` is portrait. Don't forget to add `oveflow: hidden` to the parent element.

Comment: What happens with wide viewports? (when the aspect ratio of the viewport is greater than 16/9)

Comment: @AHaworth The OP didn't specify that.

Comment: @MfyDev so it worked for all mobile versions. Just like the person above asked, how can I fix the wide viewports?

Comment: @MfyDev ok that didn't work. Your previous code work for all my media queries but the desktop version is now distorted. I just updated the question

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Check the answer again.  The edit should help you.